# Which One is More Accurate Between FQL and Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

What is the most accurate Facebook API to get the number of likes of a photo?

I used FQL and Facebook Graph API but the total number of IDs who liked the photo aren't the same with the one indicated on the Facebook page?

Answer (score 1):

FQL is more accurate than Facebook Graph API.

Comment: But it will be deprecated soon. Too bad